# Grab document text from Google Drive public document and display on Website

Tags: google-drive-api

I just had an idea to have a collaboratively worked-on public Google Drive document's contents displayed on my Web site. I was hoping this would be straightforward, as I am only going to extract simple text and the document is public, so no authentication shenanigans will bar my way.

I have looked at [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/), but turns out I can only get file metadata and/or the entire document file. Not just the document content.

I do not wish to spend a day coding to do this, I thought it would be nice to have, but can live with just linking into the file directly from my Web site. Anyone tried this before? Anyone experimented with Google Drive API and has a feel for how much work would be involved?

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking of getting the content of a native Google document (like a Google spreadsheet or a Google doc), this is currently possible with the Drive API.

In the Drive API, for Google native document types you will have a series of 'exportLinks' as part of the metadata of the file. Each  of these export URLs allow you to download the content of the Google document in a specific export format (like RTF, plain text, HTML, PDF etc...). Updating my answer...

See the documentation for this: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

Comment: Yes this is now possible through the Drive API. It works for non-public documents of course: In the Drive API, for Google native documents you will have a series of 'export URLs' each URL allows you to download the content of the Google document in a specific export format (like RTF, plain text, HTML, PDF etc...). Updating my answer...